# Is there anyway to make a way to detect audio frequency in a song to activate a event in python

Tags: python, audio, game-development

I am make a rhythm game where you click on a circle to the beat of a song and want to use the range of frequency in the song to determine where the circle is placed on the screen. For example for higher frequencies they may be placed in the top left quadrant and for lower frequency in the top right quadrant. Is there anyway of doing this in python or at all?

I have not try the problem out because I do not know where to start with the problem.

Comment: look at fast fourier transform `fft` o extract the frequencies of an audio file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.